# Xcode Breakpoint and LLDB - How do I open a file (e.g. in Preview) from a given fileURL stored in a variable?

Tags: xcode, breakpoints, lldb

I have a variable in Swift code that runs in iOS simulator and contains an existing fileURL. I want to have the file opened in macOS (not the iOS Simulator) when I hit a breakpoint.

I added an action "Shell Command" to the breakpoint to open the file. The file exists because if I copy-paste the file's path to Terminal, it opens in Preview.

[image: Xcode breakpoint with Shell Command open]

However, the Xcode console says the contrary:

```
The file /"/Users/tomkraina/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FBA16E00-9450-40E8-9650-1489A67E344C/data/Containers/Data/Application/BB97DB72-FF2A-4087-BD42-2934C63D3323/tmp/7E2303B8-0629-475A-862A-2550351FB448/OutlineExport.pdf" does not exist.
```

**First Question: How do I tell Xcode to open a file with provided fileURL in a variable on breakpoint?**

Next thing I tried was to open the file using LLDB, but I cannot find out how to evaluate a command parameter in LLDB, because backticks is only for scalars:

```
(lldb) shell open `temporaryFile.fileURL.path`
The file /105553157711856 does not exist.
```

**Second Question: How to I evaluate argument parameter to get a string in LLDB?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good answer for the first question.  It would be interesting to check whether the path that is in the Xcode error message is correct - maybe it's getting it from the value incorrectly.  If you copy the path from the error message, go to Terminal and try to open it, does that work?  Anyway, this sounds to me like a bug in Xcode.  It got some kind of path out of your variable and tried to open it, which should have worked.  If you want to follow up, it's probably best to file a bug report with the Apple Feedback.

For the second question, you have to know a little about how variables work in lldb.  Some variables have obvious values, for instance, in C a pointer has the pointer value, an integer the integer value, etc.  Other variables (any kind of Struct being the obvious example) are actually containers of other values and don't really have a "value" themselves.

lldb can show you what a swift string really is using the `--raw` option:

```
(lldb) v --raw str1
(Swift.String) str1 = {
  _guts = {
    _object = {
      _countAndFlagsBits = {
        _value = -3458764513820540912
      }
      _object = 0x8000000100003f50 (0x0000000100003f50) strings`symbol stub for: Swift.print(_: Any..., separator: Swift.String, terminator: Swift.String) -> () + 4
    }
  }
}
```

That's probably really interesting to people working on the Swift Standard Library and has the virtue of being the truth. But for most purposes, it's not a terribly useful representation.

lldb handles that problem by adding a notion of "Summary Formatters" that generate a string representation for objects based on their type.  There's one for "Swift.string" that digs around in the object, finds where the actual string is, and returns that text.  If you don't pass --raw and there's a summary formatter, then lldb will show you the summary:

```
(lldb) v str1
(String) str1 = "some string here"
```

That is also the value that you want to try and open.

The backtick syntax in lldb gets the value of the entity, not its summary, which is why that didn't work for a swift string.  However, you can fetch and act on the summaries for local variables using lldb's Python interpreter and the SB API.  So for instance:

```
(lldb) script
Python Interactive Interpreter. To exit, type 'quit()', 'exit()' or Ctrl-D.
>>> var = lldb.frame.FindVariable("str1")
>>> var.GetSummary()
'"some string here"'
```

So then if that was a file path you wanted to open, you can use Python to do that, like:

```
>>> os.system("open {0}".format(var.GetSummary()))
The file /private/tmp/some string here does not exist.
256
```

except of course your var has to hold the path to a real file...

If you want to learn more about the lldb Python API's the API docs are here:

https://lldb.llvm.org/python_api.html

and a general tutorial for using Python in lldb is here:

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html

And more information on variable formatting is here:

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html

Comment: what if this file is image and you can't just read its contents like text?

Comment: Command-line lldb only presents text data, so it won't have a way to display image data.  OTOH, if you actually run `open filename.image-extension` and the system has a viewer for `image-extension` then it will show it in the viewer for you.  Otherwise, you are still in Python, which you could also use to render the image.

Comment: could you please specify a concrete steps how to view it? For example I save a screenshot to temp directory and I can open it with terminal's command `open` or with finder (Preview app is associated with this file type) but when I execute command `open` inside a breakpoint it can't find this file.

Comment: There's not enough info here to help, you don't show the command you are trying or what errors it gets.  This seems like a separate question, trying to describe your situation in the comments of another question is pretty awkward.

Comment: I press "add action", choose "shell script", add input `echo` in the first line and `@variable@` in the second one (`variable` contains filename). I even place file in the folder with no spaces in path. I see a correct path in the console. Then I replace `echo` with `open` - I get `The file /"/Users/.../1.png" does not exist.` (file exists and could be opened with `open` via terminal)

Comment: Are you sure the path you are submitting to `open` doesn't still have quotes around it?  When lldb prints string data it always puts quotes around it (or @"..." for NSStrings) to indicate the data type, and show strings with spaces at the beginning & end.  From the error it looks like those are still in the filename when it gets passed to `open`.

Comment: If I add quotes around `open` I get error "command open doesn't exist". So `open` command is workable by itself

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I said.  My guess is that the command actually getting executed is something like `open '"/path/to/file"'`.  The lldb expression evaluation always puts quotes around the resultant string, and then Xcode is likely to do something to protect that in conning up the shell call text because it has no way of knowing the quotes aren't part of the argument value.  Then open is going to complain because there aren't any files called `"/tmp/whatever"` only ones called `/tmp/whatever`.

Comment: I don't know how to check it. The only hint I see in console is `The file /"..." does not exist.' - extra slash in output. But it doesn't mean that `open` command get this extra slash (because `echo` doesn't print it)